# AS3 Flash CS6 addChild layer setup error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

At the moment im trying to create a level class and a monster class, now in my AS code the level is created, and then the monster is created, but the monster seems to be put on top of the level graphic, I want the monsters to be under the graphic as they spawn and move to the middle screen,

This code is ran at the start of the file

```
addChild( levelStage );
```

when levelStage is created, this code is also ran

```
addChild( newMonster );
```

now the monster is on top of the levelStage graphic, i want the monster graphic to be below, should i create a new class called monsterManager which will be added to the stage first, and then spawn monsters that way? or would that not fix my problem?

Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a monsterLayer that you add before you add the levelStage. Then add your monsters to the monsterLayer.

```
var monsterLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(monsterLayer);
addChild(levelStage);

// when adding monsters 
monsterLayer.addChild(newMonster);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the display list

start here : http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/

But a simple solution right now would be to change the addChild( newMonster ); to

```
addChildAt( newMonster, 0 );
```

which puts it at the bottom of the display list behind everything else.  To view it you'll need to use  swapChild.